# How to create a flashlight sequence for android phone?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I would like to create an app which initiates a fast flash sequence (2/3 secs max) from an android phone. I have created an app which can activate the flashlight, but am struggling to change it into a flash sequence. How can I achieve this?

The flash sequence is to be used to interact with a photodiode activated door lock.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you have already managed to turn the flashlight on and off within your app, what exactly is your issue?